# What is the meaning of the word たんじゃ?

Tags: words, conjugations, contractions, explanatory-の

It is a situation which a boy who is carrying some goods after successfully escaped from chasing by policemen.

> なあ...わらって**たんじゃ**わからねえよ。

Comment: It's not a single word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Colloquial form vs. "dictionary" form***:

「わらってた」＝「わらっていた」

「ん」＝「の」

「じゃ」＝「では」

Put together, 「わらっていたのでは」 means "if you just kept laughing".

「では」, in this context, is like 「だと」 in meaning -- "if".

> 「なあ...わらってたんじゃわからねえよ。」

thus, means:

> "Y'know, I don't get the picture if you just keep laughing."

Comment: Worth noting that ん is fairly common in regular speech, even as 〜んです, and how common the contraction to じゃ is too.